# sysbio class conflicts with font size macros in tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, document-classes

The sysbio official class file has caused many problems. I find it conflict with font size macros in tikz pictures, e.g. the following MWE produces an error:

```
\documentclass{sysbio}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,draw=red,font=\large, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=2cm]{TEST TEXT};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> Undefined control sequence.
>
> \tikz@textfont ->\large
> l.8 ...arge, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=2cm]{
> TEST TEXT}; The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was
> never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and
> the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and
> I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Besides `\large`, I find that `\Large` and `\huge` also don't work, while `\small` works fine.

This is the link to the example overleaf project: [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pwdhktmhfwpk#a1f341)

Is there anything in the class file that might be the source of the issue?

Comment: Well, it seems the class does not define these commands. But you could use `\fontsize` or define the missing commands on your own.

Comment: @JasperHabicht these commands are not built-in or default commands? I thought they should work in any case

Comment: It is up to the class to define the fontsizes.

Comment: No, they aren't default or built-in. They work in many classes, but this is rather because a lot of document classes are built upon the standard classes which define these commands. The `sysbio` class, however, doesn't seem to rely on any standard class.

Comment: @TianjianQin, if you inspect sysbio.cls it doesn't load any other class, like e.g. article, which would provide \large etc. If it doesn't load (=reuse) other classes, it's simply not available by default. So anything you need: write own \newcommand s

Comment: @TianjianQin, if you look at https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class#Preliminary_declarations , then the statement \LoadClass is nowhere to find in sysbio.cls ...